# C++ constructor with one default parameter and one variable parameter

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default-arguments

I'm writing this class constructor:

```
element(int f=0, int a)
{
    first = f;
    inc = a;
    current = first - inc;
}
```

The parameters are assigned to member variables in the body of the constructor. I've been asked to get the following calls in `main()` to work:

```
prog = new element(3,5);
prog = new element(5);
```

I cannot change the order of `(3,5)`. As in within the constructor, `f` needs to be passed first, and `a` second. However, `f` needs to be initialized to 0 if no value is passed in, that way the second call keeps `f` at 0 and instead only initializes `a` to 5.

The issue with this is that I get an error if I place the parameters in this order within the constructor signature.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declaration of the constructor is invalid:

```
element(int f=0, int a)
{
    first = f;
    inc = a;
    current = first - inc;
}
```

If a parameter has a default argument, all subsequent parameters are also required to have a default argument.

What you need is to declare two constructors, like for example:

```
element(int f, int a) : first( f ), inc( a )
{
    current = first - inc;
}

element(int a) : element( 0, a )
{
}
```

It is desirable to declare the second constructor as `explicit` to prevent implicit conversions from a single integer to the `element` type:

```
explicit element(int a) : element( 0, a )
{
}
```

Comment: This is what I initially wanted to do, however the task implies I only should have one constructor. Do you think that's just a misstep on their part?

Comment: @Jad  It is impossible with one constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have parameters with default values precede normal parameters without default values. So, you need to reorder the arguments in your constructor prototype:

```
element(int a, int f=0)
{
    first = f;
    inc = a;
    current = first - inc;
}
```

Another alternative is to define an overloaded constructor:

```
element(int f, int a)
{
    first = f;
    inc = a;
    current = first - inc;
}

element(int a)
{
    first = 0;
    inc = a;
    current = first - inc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot have a non-default argument after a default argument. Default arguments must be last in the function argument list.  See [Default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

You can create an overload for the constructor:

```
element(int f, int a)
{
    first = f;
    inc = a;
    current = first - inc;
}

element(int a) : element(0,a)
{
}
```